# C#. Add polymorphism for legacy code

Tags: c#, polymorphism, legacy-code, duck-typing

Assume we have legacy classes, that can't be modified:

```
class Foo 
{
    public void Calculate(int a) { }
}

class Bar
{
    public void Compute(int a) {}
}
```

I want to write a helper with such signature:

```
void Calc(object obj, int a);
```

Notice, that the first argument is of type 'object'. The test code should be some like this:

```
ExampleX.Calc((object)new Foo(), 0);
ExampleX.Calc((object)new Bar(), 0);
```

The question is, what implementation you can imagine in addition to these:

```
// Using If/then
class Example1
{
    public static void Calc(object obj, int a)
    {
        if (obj is Foo)
            ((Foo)obj).Calculate(a);
        else if (obj is Bar)
            ((Bar)obj).Compute(a);
    }
}

// Using reflection
class Example2
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo> _methods = new Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo>();

    static Example2()
    {
        _methods.Add(typeof(Foo), typeof(Foo).GetMethod("Calculate"));
        _methods.Add(typeof(Bar), typeof(Bar).GetMethod("Compute"));
    }

    public static void Calc(object obj, int a)
    {
        _methods[obj.GetType()].Invoke(obj, new object[] { a });
    }
}

// Using delegates
class Example3
{
    private delegate void CalcDelegate(object obj, int a);

    private static Dictionary<Type, CalcDelegate> _methods = new Dictionary<Type, CalcDelegate>();

    static Example3()
    {
        _methods.Add(typeof(Foo), (o, a) => ((Foo)o).Calculate(a));
        _methods.Add(typeof(Bar), (o, a) => ((Bar)o).Compute(a));
    }

    public static void Calc(object obj, int a)
    {
        _methods[obj.GetType()](obj, a);
    }
}

// Using Reflection + overloaded methods
class Example4
{
    private delegate void CalcDelegate(object obj, int a);

    public static void Calc(object obj, int a)
    {
        Type[] types = new Type[] { 
            obj.GetType(), typeof(int)
        };

        typeof(Example4).GetMethod("Calc", types).Invoke(null, new object[] { obj, a });
    }

    public static void Calc(Foo obj, int a)
    {
        obj.Calculate(a);
    }

    public static void Calc(Bar obj, int a)
    {
        obj.Compute(a);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you attempting to get, in essence, a virtual function call?

Comment: No, I am not calling virtual function. But what would it change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for example 1, because its the simplest one and most obvious.

I would use Example 2 only if you expect new types of objects with one of these two methods, and example 3 only if you have a lot (tens if not hundreds)  of objects and performance starts being an issue.

Edit: Or extension methods if you are .Net 3

Answer (score 3):

Use extension methods to essentially add a new function to an existing type.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Comment: Extension whould not add polymorphism by itself. I added Example4, that uses the similar approach. Extension code whould be almost the same.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would write the solution.  It reduces the risk of type safety problems in the code and eliminates reflection.

```
class Example2
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, Action<object,int>> _methods = new Dictionary<Type, Action<object,int>>();

    static Example2()
    {
        Add<Foo>( (f,a) => f.Calculate(a) );
        Add<Bar>( (b,a) => b.Compute(a) );
    }

    public static void Calc<TSource>(TSource source, int a)
    {
        _methods[typeof(TSource)](source,a);
    }

    public static void Add<TSource>(Action<TSource,int> del) 
    {
        Action<object,int> wrapper = (x,i) => { del((TSource)x, i); }; 
        _methods[typeof(TSource)] = wrapper;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could always use the [adapter pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternAdapter.aspx) to implement the unchangeable legacy objects, without breaking any objects dependant on its functionality, while still being ableto implement your own (new) functionality to the object.